# How to transform array of objects into object of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have seen lots of answers in the other way,
but i couldnt find array of objects into object of objects

the following example of what I want:
i want to transform this:

```
var = [
{"a" : {"min" : 0.5}},
{"b" : {"max" : 0.6}},
{"c" : {"min" : 0.3}}]
```

to this:

```
var = {
"a" : {"min" : 0.5},
"b" : {"max" : 0.6},
"c" : {"min" : 0.3}
}
```

array of objets to object of objects,

So I can use this solver: https://github.com/JWally/jsLPSolver

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `Object.assign()` and ES6 spread syntax.

```js
var arr = [{"a" : {"min" : 0.5}}, {"b" : {"max" : 0.6}}, {"c" : {"min" : 0.3}}]

var result = Object.assign({}, ...arr);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I would favor this

Answer (score 1):

```
const obj = arr.reduce((result, item) => {
  const key = Object.keys(item)[0];
  result[key] = item[key];
  return result; 
}, {});
```

[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control) and [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) are your friends in here.

I think it is kind of difficult to generalize this and make it more generic, since you have to know which key of the item should be used as key of the result. But in this case, there is only one, so easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should create class or struct of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. First loop over the array and just add the key & value from each object to the new object

```js
var firstArray = [{
    "a": {
      "min": 0.5
    }
  },
  {
    "b": {
      "max": 0.6
    }
  },
  {
    "c": {
      "min": 0.3
    }
  }
]

var arrayKey = {};
firstArray.forEach(function(item) {
  for (var keys in item) {
    arrayKey[keys] = item[keys]
  }


})
console.log(arrayKey)
```